# Author deleted a cocoapods repo breaking my project. How to use backed up repo files to fix?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

As per title, the developer of DRDynamicSlideShow deleted the repository which broke my project after running a pod install.

I have a backup of all the files from the repository, and tried to manually add the library to the project by copying the .h and .m file into a searched path in the project folder.

The project was working perfectly prior to the pod install, so I have made no modifications to any code other than copying the .h and .m files over.

When I try to run the project I get the error:

> Property 'DRDynamicSlideShowdelegate' not found on object of type
>   'RMDateSelectionViewController *'

The code:

```
- (void)didTapOnDueButton:(UIButton *)button {

    [self hideKeyboard];

    RMDateSelectionViewController *dateSelectionVC = [RMDateSelectionViewController dateSelectionController];

    dateSelectionVC.DRDynamicSlideShowdelegate = self;

    [dateSelectionVC show];
}
```

I'm lost and would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: can you see "DRDynamicSlideShowdelegate" on the .h file?, might have been on a separate file

Comment: I dont see "DRDynamicSlideShowdelegate" in the .h file. Note also that when I cmd-click on "DRDynamicSlideShowdelegate" I get a "symbol not found" error.

Comment: Are you sure the developer deleted the repo? I can access the [RMDateSelectionViewController](https://github.com/CooperRS/RMDateSelectionViewController). I suggest you to use git for your project to keep all the dependencies.

Comment: Hey that's not the repo that was deleted. It's DRDynamicSlideShow that was deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might be interested in locking to a release in your Podfile,

Doing something [like](https://github.com/artsy/eigen/blob/master/Podfile#L40):

```
 pod 'JSDecoupledAppDelegate', '1.1.0'
```

And running `pod install` will lock it to that [version](https://github.com/CooperRS/RMDateSelectionViewController/releases) and you won't get anymore API breaking surprises.

Comment: I can't add the pod back because the repository is deleted (all versions).

Comment: You can use de-centralized CocoaPods instead if it was removed from trunk: `pod 'RMDateSelectionViewController', :git => "https://github.com/CooperRS/RMDateSelectionViewController.git", :tag => "1.5.0"`

Answer (score 0):

Better answer, looks like DRDynamicSlideShow was renamed to Popsicle. You should ask them to push another podspec to DRDynamicSlideShow with `deprecated_in_favor_of` ( [guide](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#deprecated_in_favor_of) ) so that people are less confused. You could use a [fork](https://github.com/Janak-Nirmal/DRDynamicSlideShow) instead.

Comment: Hey it wasn't renamed. All method names have changed etc, so it requires a some rewrites (and another library). I appreciate the suggestion but I have the repository files, I'd rather use those (as per the question title).

Comment: Then you want to refer to an older build in your podfile, see the above answer.

Comment: How would that work? All builds have been taken offline by the developer.

Answer (score 0):

Other than implementing the author's new project (which has some of the same functionality), I had to delete the pod and remove the delegate.